# Regrouping array elements based on two attributes

Tags: javascript

I have an array such as this one :

```
let array1 = [
{"id":"A", "serial":"C"},
{"id":"A", "serial":"E"},
{"id":"A", "serial":"B"},
{"id":"A", "serial":"B"},
{"id":"B", "serial":"A"},
{"id":"B", "serial":"C"},
{"id":"C", "serial":"B"},
{"id":"C", "serial":"F"}
]
```

I would like to regroup by same id-serial pairs. {"id":"X", "serial":"Y"} and {"id":"Y", "serial":"X"} should be considered same pairs.

As an expected result :

```
let res = [
[{"id":"A", "serial":"C"}],
[{"id":"A", "serial":"E"}],
[{"id":"A", "serial":"B"},{"id":"A", "serial":"B"},{"id":"B", "serial":"A"}],
[{"id":"B", "serial":"C"},{"id":"C", "serial":"B"}],
[{"id":"C", "serial":"F"}]
]
```

How can I acchieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couldn't think of a better way to do this. one approach would be to group by a unique key. here a unique key would `A|B` for both combinations `{"id":"A", "serial":"B"}` and `{"id":"A", "serial":"B"}`

```js
let array1 = [
{"id":"A", "serial":"C"},
{"id":"A", "serial":"E"},
{"id":"A", "serial":"B"},
{"id":"A", "serial":"B"},
{"id":"B", "serial":"A"},
{"id":"B", "serial":"C"},
{"id":"C", "serial":"B"},
{"id":"C", "serial":"F"}
]

const res = Object.values(array1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const k = [curr.id, curr.serial].sort().join('|');
  (acc[k] ??= []).push(curr);
  return acc;
}, {}));


console.log(res)
```

Comment: This works as intended, thank you

Comment: @JK2018 just a note if you avoid the `;` this breaks and you will have to write `acc[k] ??= []` and `acc[k].push(curr)` as 2 steps